# GetTypes from an Assembly that is an external dll

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 projects in my solution.  My first project is trying to search for all classes that are in a specific namespace and implement a specific interface.

My website runs of the first project and imports the second as a compiled dll.  Now if I were to try and search for assemblies in a namespace that resides in my first project, then I have no issues, however the moment that I point to my second project, it can never find anything.  Here is my code:

```
const string @namespace = "MySecondProject.Models";
var reports = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                      where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace && typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                select t;
```

I have also tried setting up the namespace variable to include second project name as i know this can be an issue when creating an instance of an object via reflection (encountered that before)

```
const string @namespace = "MySecondProject.Models,MySecondProject";
```

I am trying to understand why I am getting back no results and what is the correct way of doing this?

I have also tried removing my interface check, but I still get same results.

Edit:

Here is the working code example for future visitors:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("MySecondProject");
const string @namespace = "MySecondProject.Models";
var reports = from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                      where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace && typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                    select t;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is only going to list the types of the executing assembly, in other words the assembly in which that code resides.

If you want to interrogate a different assembly then you must specifically load that assemblies types.

Example:

```
var a = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.LoadFrom( assemblyFilename);
```

If you are on a web server and load an assembly and that assembly filename path is the \bin folder then you will end up locking that assembly, that will prevent you from updating the website by dropping new versions of the assembly.  You want to get the execution path and look for the assembly name there.  IIS creates a temp folder and copies all the assemblies there and runs from there.  That allows you to update the source \bin which spawns new app domains.  You don't want to lose that ability.

Also, always use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()` to instantiate objects via reflection.

To get the *runtime* folder:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/bin"
```

Comment: Would you be able to give me code example of how that would look like?  I tried `Assembly.Load("MySecondProject");` on which it did not crash, but my search is still empty.

Comment: Lookup Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom.

Comment: If you intend to instantiate and use classes from the loaded assembly use Assembly.LoadFrom.

Comment: @Kevin the problem is that if I instantiate that in a variable, I cannot then call `.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()` because it is in a static context.  I am trying to figure out how to get around that.

Comment: The assembly you have programmatically loaded is NOT the executing assembly. The assembly where your code is running from is the executing assembly.

Comment: a simple way to get around that is to place that `.GetExecutingAssembly()` call in one of your classes in that assembly, in other words all you have to do is execute that code in that class.. perhaps use an interface on one of the classes and use it for that purpose.

Comment: Once you have loaded an assembly, the variable contains an assembly, you don't need to call GetExecutingAssembly on it, just call GetTypes.

Comment: I agree with that too ^^^

Comment: ok, I'm starting to understand where I'm getting all confused.  @TMcKeown you said that if I call `a.GetTypes()` I would now lock up that dll file and I will not be able to update it unless I stop the IIS server?  If that is correct, I am not certain I understand your explanation of how to get around that.

Comment: I'll post an edit, this is only a recommendation if you are using shadow copy for your web app

Comment: @TMcKeown I am not sure what you mean by shadow copy.  I have posted an edit in my question to show you how I have it working right now.  Should I change how I am loading that assembly?  Or is this scenario not considered as shadow copy.  Sorry, never heard that term before.

Comment: Checkout shadow copy... it's another topic, but essentially if you want to drag and drop updates without restarting IIS you'll need to load the assembly located in your shadow copied folder.

Comment: i think you are probably fine because you aren't specifying a full path.. so my guess is it is using the current runtime folder and that will work